# Finding image and pre-image of set

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have this question I'm kind of stuck on.

> Consider the function $f:\mathbb{Z}\to{}\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$
>    defined by $f(x)=[2x]$.
>
> i) Compute $f^{-1}(B)$ for each of  $$ B=\{ [0]\} \qquad B=\{ [1],
>  [2]\}  \qquad B=\{ [0], [2]\}  \qquad B=\{ [0], [2], [4] \}.  $$
>
> ii) Compute $f(A)$ for each of  $$ A= \mathbb{Z}^+  \qquad A=\{ x\in
>  \mathbb{Z} : x\hbox{ is even}\}  \qquad A=\{ x\in \mathbb{Z} : x\hbox{
>  is odd}\} . $$

I'm not 100% sure how to do this problem. This is what I would do $$f^{-1}(\{[0]\}) = \{0\}$$$$f^{-1}(\{[1],[2]\}) = \{\frac{1}{2}, 1\}$$ However $\frac{1}{2} \notin \mathbb{Z}$. So, I'm not sure what to do. Thanks.

Also, for part ii, would it be $f(\mathbb{Z}^+) = [\text{ all even numbers}]$?

Comment: $f^{-1}([0])$ should be $3\mathbb Z$

Comment: @Rise how did you get that?

Comment: the map sends every integer to its equivalence class of 2 times it mod 6. The only numbers that could possibly be in the class of zero are obviously multiples of 6 and since the map multiplies everything by 2 also multiples of 3 will go to 0 as 2 times 3 is 6. Is this clear to you or should I explain better?

Comment: @Rise I think I get it, but what would $f^{-1}(\{[1], [2]\})$ be?

Comment: I'll give you a hint - $f^{-1}([1])$ is empty (why?) So only find $f^{-1}([2])$

Comment: @Rise Is it because the only numbers that will have a remainder of 1 when divided by 6 are odd? But since we first multiply by 2 it will always be even. So would $f^{-1}([2]) = 4\mathbb{Z}$? and would this mean that $f^{-1}(\{[1], [2]\}) = 4\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32599/discussion-between-rise-and-kfc).